# How to disable creation of .eh symbols in library

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have built an executable linking it with curl and other custom libraries. Though executable is getting built successfully but I am getting the following warnings:

```
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_urldecode.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _curl_free.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_blockread_all.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_SOCKS4.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_SOCKS5.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_http_setup_conn.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_http.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_http_done.eh
ld: warning, can't find matching function for eh symbol _Curl_http_connect.eh
```

These seems to be some symbols helpful for debugging and alike but I don't want these symbols as well as the warnings of such sort. I read through some posts and passed the following CFLAGS while building the executable

```
-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -dead_strip
```

But it didn't work. Any clue regarding these .eh symbols and meaning of functions for this symbols. I just want to suppress these warnings.

Comment: Anybody out there ? Do I need to add more info.